# ChartJS: Multi line xAxis Label in Time series line chart

Tags: chart.js

I have created a sample line chart taken from the chartJS examples and changed the labels and added a configuration to make it a time series chart.

Here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/w6dor1f3](https://jsfiddle.net/w6dor1f3/)

My problem is how to split the xAxis label to multi-line. In the code, I changed the format of the date to 'DD-MMM HH:mm'. So if I have '01-Jan 12:00' I want to display it as:

```
12:00
01-Jan
```

After looking for some solutions, I found out that you can do so by converting your label into an array. For example, instead of "01-Jan 12:00", you could have ["12:00","01-Jan"]. However, I found out that this doesn't work if the xAxis scale is of type 'time'.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

In case you're wondering, I used time scale in order for the chartjs-plugin-zoom to work.